# Lotus Notes Inbox issue

Tags: email, ibm-domino

I have a clustered environment of two domino servers. What I find is that in the active server of the cluster the mail "Inbox" is empty. But then the views-> "All Documents"/"All Emails" shows that documents are there. And added to that we see that in the the non-active server in the cluster, the inbox is not empty. So basically can the inbox get corrupted in some situations?. If so how to repair the inbox?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> And added to that we see that in the the non-active server in the cluster, the inbox is not empty.

Basically, that sounds like replication isn't working between your two Domino servers.  Sure, the Notes Inbox view can get corrupted (as can any view or database), [and there are tools and commands to repair corrupt databases, such as fixup and updall](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Database_Corruption_Troubleshooting_Guide), but it doesn't sound like that will help here.

Fix your Domino server cluster replication first, then fixup your database, if needed.  You might want to start by [forcing replication between your cluster members](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_admin.nsf/89d3962efd85426f85256b870069c0aa/874eef1f551d38bb85256c1d003998ab?OpenDocument), and then move on to [more involved troubleshooting tools and techniques](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_admin.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/8765a261a8ca81c585256c1d0039dfcf?OpenDocument).  The log.nsf file is your friend here - look through it to determine why that view or database is out of sync between the two replicas, and correct the issue.

Comment: Yes thanks for your feedback. It now really looks a replication issue.

Answer (score 0):

This most probably is not a replication issue. Either the index of your inbox on one server is corrupt, or you have two folders named inbox in that database, and one server shows the "right" one, and the other the "wrong" one. You can rebuild the index of inbox using updall with -R (rebuild) and -T (define view) options:

`lo updall mail\db.nsf -R -T ($Inbox)`

Or you check with Designer Client for existance of a second Inbox and delete one of them (take care to get the right one: first rename one and then move the documents to the one left over)